# why withApollo's query doesn't receive props?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

Code below, when this component loaded it will send two queries, then in the  life cycle method, I checked if some info is exist such as `id` in this example. if this `id` is exist, it will execute another **new** query base on this `id`.

the thing is the `query` is success resolve and the back `data` is the real info I wanted, but I can't find it in **this.props.data** (the `this.props.data` is undefined) in the render function.

What's the problem of this approach, and why the `this.props.data` is undefined?

```
class UserInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.wechat.wechatUser && nextProps.wechat.wechatUser.binded > 0) {
      const id = nextProps.wechat.wechatUser.binded;
      this.props.client
        .query({
          query: QUERY_PLAYER,
          fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
          variables: {
            id,
          },
        })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.data.player) {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.data.player.name}
        </div>
      );
    }

    return <div>loading</div>;
  }
}

const WECHATUSER_QUERY = gql`
  query WechatUser($id: Int!) {
    wechatUser(id: $id) {
      id
      nickname
      sex
      city
      province
      openid
      unionid
      headimgurl
      role_id
      game_id
      type_id
      parent_id
      tel
      disabled
      remainder
      created_at
      updated_at
      language
      weixin_account
      is_api_user
      binded
    }
  }
`;
const QUERY_TYPE = gql`
  {
    listAgentCategory {
      id
      name
      num
      price
      profit
      investment
    }
  }
`;

const QUERY_PLAYER = gql`
  query player($id: Int!) {
    player(id: $id) {
      id
      roomid
      headimg
      name
      sex
      lv
      exp
      coins
      gems
      roomid
      reg_time
      login_time
      logout_time
      online_time
      lock
      platform
      agent
    }
  }
`;

const withData = graphql(QUERY_TYPE, { name: 'agentType' })(
  graphql(WECHATUSER_QUERY, {
    name: 'wechat',
    options: props => ({
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      variables: {
        id: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userinfo')).user.id,
      },
    }),
  })(UserInfo)
);

export default withApollo(withData);
```

Comment: In the given code block, where did you use `this.props.data`?

Comment: @JudeNiroshan cause in my render function I need the info from `this.porps.data` such as `<div>{this.props.data&&this.props.data.name}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

As you are receiving the result from an asynchronous call, you should use the `state`. You cannot modify the `props`. The convention is to use the `state` object in a scenario like this.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
                   data: ''
                  };
}
```

then, modify your componentWillReceiveProps() as follows:

```
  this.props.client
    .query({
      query: QUERY_PLAYER,
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      variables: {
        id,
      },
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
          this.setState({
              'data': data
          });
       });
    });
```

then use this in your render() like below:

```
<div>{this.state.data && this.state.data.name}</div>
```

Hope this will help you. :-)

Comment: IMO, it's counter-pattern with react and react-apollo, `react-apollo` container      give u the access to props properties directly.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know about that. I just tried to help you with what I know. :)